# How can I add HTML horizontal hr line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a horizontal line under the buttons as a spacer. How do I use hr to add a line that does not scale when zooming the webpage (the red line in the picture)?

[image]

The items on the page is middle centered. Like so:

[image]

The red lines were added later on.

Thank you

```css
[class^="item"] {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-areas: "title title img" "buttons buttons img" "main main img" "main main other1";
  padding: 12px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  min-width: 1300px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: title;
  font-size: 31px;
  height: 50%;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: img;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: buttons;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: main;
  transform: translateY(calc(-86px + 40px));
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: other1;
  transform: translateY(-65px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">1 Fallout</div>
  <div class="item2">2
    <img src="../../Img/Game Covers/Fallout1Cover.bmp" width="165" height="241">
  </div>
  <div class="item3">3
    <a href="fallout1Characters.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Characters</button></a>
    <a href="fallout1Locations.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Locations</button></a>
    <a href="fallout1Items.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Items</button></a>
    <button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item4">4 Fallout: A Post Nuclear Role Playing Game is an open-world turn-based role-playing video game developed and published by Interplay Productions in 1997. The game has a post-apocalyptic and retro-futuristic setting, in the aftermath of a global nuclear
    war in an alternate history timeline mid-22nd century. The protagonist of Fallout is an inhabitant of a Vault, long-term shelters, who is tasked to find a replacement Water Chip and save their Vault.
  </div>
  <div class="item5">ttt</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the `<hr />` to be the width of the group of `<button>` elements? Incidentally it's invalid HTML to nest an interactive element - such as a `<button>` - within another interactive element - such as an `<a>`. With the one exception of nesting form-elements, such as `<input>`, `textarea`, etc within a `<label>`.

Comment: try a div with in the div, make the outerdiv a flex container and the inner div have a height of 1px (or how thick you want the bar to be) then align it center. See ref: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Add a hr tag as shown below inside the div with classname 'item3'

```
<div class="item3">3
                <a href="fallout1Characters.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Characters</button></a>
                <a href="fallout1Locations.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Locations</button></a>
                <a href="fallout1Items.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Items</button></a>
                <button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">4</button>

                <hr class="spacer">

            </div>
```

2.add below css

```
.spacer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -33px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

3.add position relative to class .item3

Answer (score 0):

there is some different way at first you can set an hr in your view and with some help of css `transform` rotate that

the other hand you can set border next of item like hr and set space for that

Comment: I have tried to add a hr in a div, so I have gotten a horizontal line, but I cannot figure out how to position it in the correct location and make it nonscalable (see pics for reference). The line moves when zooming in (to the left).